# Linear programming - optimizing profit with tricky constraints

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, glpk

I want to solve a linear optimization problem with binary decision variables to be solved in R (currently I am using the Rglkp package). However I am having trouble setting up the constraints.

Suppose a company wants to decide what quarters to sell their product to maximize their profit. But, if they want to sell they must sell in at least 3 quarters in a row. This is an example of what their profits might look like.

```
profits <- tibble(year = 1,
              quarter = 1:4, 
              profit = c(23, -4, 6, -2))
```

I could then set up an Rglpk constraint matrix and solve as below.

```
cons.m <- matrix(c( 2, -1, -1,  0,
                   -2,  3, -2, -1,
                   -1, -2,  3, -1,
                    0, -1, -2,  2),
             nrow = 4, byrow = T)

solution <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = profits$profit,
                           mat = cons.m,
                           dir = rep("<=", 4),
                           rhs = rep(0, 4),
                           types = rep("B", 4),
                           max = T)


solution$solution
[1] 1 1 1 0
```

Which says I should sell in the first 3 quarters and not sell in Q4. This is clearly the correct solution.

How could I extend this solution to work with 12 periods, where I must sell at least 5 quarters in a row?

```
profits.new <- tibble(year = rep(1:3, each = 4),
                  quarter = 1:12, 
                  profit = runif(12, -20, 20))
```

I realize I can generate all combinations and then select the maximum that meets the requirements, but I want a solution the can generalize to much larger cases where there would be too many combinations.

Answer (score 3):

This can be modeled as:

[image]

where *n* is the minimum length of a production run.

This will only require `T=12` constraints.

The total number of possible production runs >= n (with `n=5, T=12`) is **42**.

Of course, this difference will increase (rather dramatically) for longer planning horizons. E.g. for `T=24,n=5` we have **24** constraints vs **4316** possible solutions.

An optimal solution can look like:

[image]

There is much [more to say](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/03/production-scheduling-minimum-up-time.html) about constraints like this.